# C# get properties, and properties of child fields recursivly

Tags: c#, recursion, properties, field, expandoobject

I'm trying to convert an object to an ExpandoObject.

So far I've got arrays of both the Properties and the Fields,

```
Type type = data.GetType();
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
```

I can easily walk through the props and get the value of each one, and add that to my ExpandoObject:

```
public static ExpandoObject ConvertToExpandoObject(object data)
{
    var dynObj = new ExpandoObject(); 

    Type type = data.GetType();
    FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
    PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

    // first the properties...
    foreach (var property in props)
    {
        // add this property
        ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynObj).Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(data,null));

    }
}
```

But then for each Field I want to call the convert method again thus:

```
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    // add this field
    ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynObj).Add(field.Name,ConvertToExpandoObject(field?? as an object));               
}
```

Being as I don't know the type of the Field in question, although it is in field.FieldType, how do I go about converting the field into an object of its own type to pass into the convert function?

EDIT:

Full text as one block to hopefully make it clearer:

```
public static ExpandoObject ConvertToExpandoObject(object data)
{
    var dynObj = new ExpandoObject(); 

    Type type = data.GetType();
    FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
    PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

    // first the properties...
    foreach (var property in props)
    {
        // add this property
        ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynObj).Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(data,null));

    }
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
         // add this field
         ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynObj).Add(field.Name,ConvertToExpandoObject(field?? as an object));               
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Example objects - they are trivial. It may be academic now as I can easily foresee when they wouldn't be... might go back to the drawing board

```
class Parent
{
    public string parentVar { get; set; }
    public Child child { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public string childvar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert the fields' values to `ExpandoObject`s leaving the properties' values as they are?

Comment: Smells *really* fishy.  You either add the field value as-is or you expand it to an ExpandoObject, you cannot do both.  Also rather unclear why you'd do this for a field but not a property, makes little sense.  I suspect you'll run into plenty of trouble when you actually try to use the returned ExpandoObject if the object is non-trivial.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining it properly. I have an object that only had properties, and was converting that to an ExpandoObject - all was good. Then in the course of things I had another object that had not just properties, but also child objects (fields?), each of these need to be converted to an ExpandoObject and added as a child of the output ExpandoObject

Comment: You are describing the "object is non-trivial" failure mode I warned you about.  A simple counter-example is a field of type *int*, you do not want to convert that to an ExpandoObject.  Ultimately the type of a field isn't any different from the type of a property so they should be treated the same way.  If a property is of type *Customer*, should *that* be converted to an ExpandoObject?  If you say "no" then a field of type Customer should not be converted either.

Comment: Lets assume the objects are trivial, which they are. I'll post some example objects to further clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at it from a different viewpoint,
The ultimate object was to convert to an ExpandoObject before serializing it to send to the web client. This is so properties can be removed based on the users authorization..

So I just serialized it first, then removed the properties..

```
ExpandoObject dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
```